# How to negotiate contract specific salary duration

Tags: salary, negotiation

Currently I am in a non-remunerated internship in a company and I'm going to finish it in about 1 month. I was told by my tutor that there's a big chance for them to hire me, the usual contract duration is 1 year but the salary for the first 6 months is a little less than the last 6 months(they do this to test new employees). Also, although the company has a lot of employees (around 200), it's like a startup in terms of organization, so I think I could discuss it with HR and the CEO.

So my question is, since I've been working for 3 months for free, should I negotiate the "test salary" duration? And if so, how should I approach the negotiation?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I haven't done it since he's part of the company too, should i ask him first?

Comment: Ultimately, the only answer to any negotiation (of any kind) is that you need *other possibilities*.  You should firmly try to secure *another* job altogether.  If they offer you X, the only possible way you can say "no thanks" is, if, you have another job lined-up.

Answer (score 1):

> they do this to test new employees

This is a load of crap.  They do this to line their pockets with a few more bucks.  It's a negotiating tactic.  You might be *promised*   a future increase, but the person who's making promises isn't putting a specific date or amount-of-increase into your *written contract*.  Without said specific writing, they're just blowing smoke up you-know-where.

If you're a competent developer, why is it that your work on day 1 should be valued at less than your work six months after that point?  Look, you don't buy a car, groceries, or anything of value by way of a "test" deal.  I've never heard of a "test" mortgage.

Nine times out of ten when a company tells you that they'll review your performance at some interval after your start date, it's a ploy to get you to shut up and accept less.  And six or nine months after your start date, you've become comfortable in your role and are less likely to bail out.  Also, if you start asking about an increase and get nowhere, it's more challenging to try and find the job that pays what you want if you're already working and your boss knows you're dissatisfied.

Get your worth from the start, or go elsewhere.

Comment: You buy all kinds of things with an initial discount, including mortgages. And people who are as valuable day 1 as they are at six months are rarer than hens teeth.